# Download folders from Ubuntu 1

Tags: ubuntu-one

How can I download folders from U-1 now that is shutting down? It seems that it will only allow downloading of single files.

Alternately, can I install u-1 in 14.04 so that I could sync?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a feature to download all your files easily, prior to all the files being deleted. Developers are working on the feature, and it will be deployed as soon as it is tested and working. You will be able to then download all of your files as a single `.zip` file.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ubuntuone-client](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntuone-client) package, sync and uninstall. I'm not sure if the client will be removed from the archives, but it will no longer be installed by default and will be uninstalled in an upgrade.

Considering the fact that the Ubuntu One service will be open sourced, it seems strange that it should be removed from the archives.

Comment: Ubuntu software center says "ubuntuone-client" not available.

Comment: It's available here. I don't know what to tell you. In any case, they will provide you with tools to extract your data.

Comment: Yes, One file at a time rather than a folder. I'll be here all day. Are you using 14.04?